# cvPyrDown() can somebody help me to modify this line

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I am newbie to openCv, trying to analyze some code.
I know this line works fine and reduce destination by two but i want it to change to some other sizes, how can i change? Specifically "CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5"

cvPyrDown(frame, half_frame, CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5);

Comment: please use the c++ api instead, cv::pyrDown has an additional Size parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot resize the image to **any** desired size by using `pyrDown()` because it will always resize your image by a **factor of 2**. Similar is the case with `pyrUp()`.

If you want to resize your image to any desired size then you must use the `resize()`

```
cvResize(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, int interpolation=CV_INTER_LINEAR )
```

the detailed documentation about it is given [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize).